# Debug - reading scanner input issue

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I'm using Eclipse to run the following simple program ( test scanner )
The inputs are mentioned in the Run Configuration -> Arguments section  as

```
23 98
```

The program does not terminate - hangs without producing a + b

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class InputExpt
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

      int a = in.nextInt();
      int b = in.nextInt();
      in.close();
      System.out.println(a+b);
   }
}
```

The program works when I dont use the Scanner utility to read inputs. Using lines below displays 121(a+b)

```
     int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // in.nextInt();
     int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //in.nextInt();
```

What is the issue here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between program input and program arguments.

When you put run configuration arguments, Eclipse adds them to the `java` launcher

```
java InputExpt 23 98
```

For you to get console input, you would run and enter the numbers (pressing carriage return when you are done entering what you need to)

```
> java InputExpt
> 23 98
>
```

Program arguments are bound as elements to the `args` array while program input is streamed in the java process input stream which you can get through `System.in`.

Answer (score 1):

1) `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);`

the above code will read from STDIN and you are passing data using command-line arguments

2)

```
 int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // in.nextInt();
 int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //in.nextInt();
```

the code above works as you passed data using cmd-args